# Can you make an object iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, iterable

I have some `class`:

```
import numpy as np

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
        self.y = np.array([1,4,9,16])
```

is there a neat way to iterate over `x` and `y` for some instance of `SomeClass` in Python? Currently to iterate over the variables I would use:

```
some_class = SomeClass()
for x, y in zip(some_class.x, some_class.y):
    print(x, y)
```

... but can you define `SomeClass`'s behaviour such that the same would work:

```
some_class = SomeClass()
for x, y in some_class:
    print(x, y)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you want a 'neat way' -> `for i in SomeClass(np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([1,4,9,16])):`
```
class SomeClass(zip):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        return zip.__new__(cls, *args)
```

Comment: @bison too neat ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `__iter__` dunder method:

```py
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
        self.y = np.array([1,4,9,16])

    def __iter__(self):
        # This will yield tuples (x, y) from self.x and self.y
        yield from zip(self.x, self.y)

for x, y in SomeClass():
   print(x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks - works a charm ...